Local server behind FritzBox not accessible from the internet
I have a raspberry pi running a Nextcloud behind a FritzBox with a DS Lite tunnel from Vodafone. The pi is accessible from my local network and was accessible from the internet until around the time that I also installed Pihole, but I can't figure out what could be going wrong since then.
I've set up a MyFritz!Net account and my FritzBox is accessible via IPv6 with a link such as https://mysubdomain.myfritz.net:45678. I've also configured IPv6 http and https port sharing for my pi in addition to having a placeholder port (65001) so that the pi gets a myfritz link, however, mypi.mysubdomain.myfritz.net:65001 does not work (nor do http/https ports). When I use ping <my Pi's IPv6 as determined by the ip command> from outside of my home network, it says Administratively prohibited (whereas it works locally).
I followed AVM's instructions on how to configure port sharing, namely:

[X] Checked that my router is accessible from the internet
[x] Set up port sharing for 80, 443 and 65001 (myfritz!net)
[X] Checking externally assigned ports: They're the same as what I assigned (80, 443, 65001)
[X] Internect connection: "Maintain permanently" was checked
[X] No parental controls are enabled
[X] NetBIOS filter: Does not apply
[X] Pi's firewall: There should be no changes as to when it worked and it still does for local connections, so this should not be the cause.

So what could be the issue here? Something related to the Apache webserver running nextcloud and the pihole interface (which are both accessible from the local network)? Or the fact that the setup for pihole required me to change the DNS to the Pi's IP? Or is it a newly arisen ISP issue?

Found the solution: My problem was in my FritzBox's port sharing settings. Due to a new IPv6 address of my pi after its restart, the IPv6 interface ID should was incorrect as it still pointed to the old IP. Manually updating it solved my problem.
